# routing to a component within router-outlet

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, router-outlet

I have an app with several routes, one of them with children. My issue is that I would have to somehow "overwrite" what the `<router-outlet>` displays from within one of the components that it displays.

My route-tree looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    path: 'path1',
    component: 'Comp1'
  },
  {
    path: 'path2',
    component: 'Comp2'
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'product-container',
        component: EditComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have my app.component.html set up like this:

```
<div class="nav">
  <a [routerLink]="['path1']">Path 1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['path2']">Path 2</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['products']">Products</a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

now inside the ProductsComponent, I have a button that needs to link to the EditComponent, a page meant to edit a product or add a new one.
So I made a button like this inside of it:

```
<a [routerLink]="['product-container']">Add</a>
```

The path it links to is `products/product-container`, which to me seems correct. Though clicking it, while navigation works in itself (url in browser changes), the displayed content never changes. Obviously, adding another `<router-outlet>` in my products page will display the EditComponent inside it.

The question now is: Is there a way to "overwrite" the `<router-outlet>` in the app.component.html to display the EditComponent instead of the ProductComponent when I press the "Add" button in ProductComponent?

Or would I alternatively have to let the Add button switch between two page-parts with their own ngIf or something like that?

---

Edit: 
Another option I thought off would be to place both ProductComponent and EditComponent in their own RoutingModule and on the same level, then create a "parent" component for both and have them share one `<router-outlet>` within that parent component. Though I'd prefer seeing if there are other options first before I implement something like that.

Comment: The approach in your edit is what I did, and it works fine. You just need to add a redirect child path to go by default to your Products component when hitting the new parent: `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'products', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: I suppose that's the only "proper" solution then?

Comment: to add in: does that still not cause problems when having the navigation button inside the ProductComponent instead of the parent component?

Comment: As long as your routerLinks are set correctly, it should be fine.

Comment: alright, will wait a little longer to see if I find an alternative (really want to know if there are other options) and then, if nothing comes up, will do it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I followed the idea I had posted under "Edit" on my original question.

I created a ProductsModule and a ProductsRoutingModule.
ProductsRoutingModule now has a (also newly created) ProductsContainerComponent in which the HTML consists only of `<router-outlet>` and which in the routeTree has both the ProductsComponent and EditComponent as children.

ProductsModule has of course been made known in the AppModule.

Inside the EditComponent (and ProductsComponent respectively) I simply have:

```
constructor (private router: Router) {
}

// triggered on button-click
navigate() { 
  this.router.navigate['products'];
}
```

and it works just fine. Though my IDE tells me that I do not handle/react to the promise this returns, so that's something I still have to take care of. Otherwise, this solution worked for me.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue who stumbles upon this post.

Comment: taken care of it! sorry, with having to wait 2 days, I kinda forgot